# How to make a Tron game in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I want to make a 2 player tron game in Assembly in VGA mode. The first player will be controlled with arrow keys, and draws in oreange. The second uses w,a,s,d and draws in blue. I have the code for one of them, but not sure how to implement another one: I know it's not a good idea to use the same registers for both of them, but not sure either what should I use instead.

Here's the full code:

```
Code    Segment
    assume CS:Code, DS:Data, SS:Stack

Start:
    mov ax, Code
    mov DS, AX


Menu:
;Screen clear
    mov ax, 03h
    int 10h
    
;Kurzor position
    mov ah, 02h
    mov bh, 0
    mov dh, 10          ;row
    mov dl, 30          ;column
    int 10h

;Menu
    mov dx, offset gamestart
    mov ah, 09
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset empty
    mov ah, 09
    int 21h

    mov dx, offset exit
    mov ah, 09
    int 21h

;Wait for button press
    xor ax, ax
    int 16h

;Examine pressed button
    cmp al, '1'
    jz Startgame

    cmp al, '2'
    jz Program_End_Helper

Startgame:
;First player pos
    mov dl, 100
    mov dh, 100
    push dx

;Second player pos
    mov dl, 200
    mov dh, 100
    push dx

    mov ax, 13h             ;Change mode (VGA)
    int 10h
    mov ax, 0a000h          ;Video 
    mov es, ax              ;Extra segment

Draw:
    pop dx                  ;dx contains Y(dh) and X(dl)
    xor ah, ah
    mov al, dh              ;ax-ben Y koordináta
    push dx                 ;dx mentése, mul utasítás felülírja
    mov bx, 128     ;320
    mul bx                  ;Y koordináta * 320
    pop dx                  ;dx-ben Y(dh), X(dl) koordináta
    add al, dl              ;X koordináta hozzáadása
    jnc Pixel
    inc ah                  ;van átvitel

Pixel:
    push dx
    mov di, ax

    mov al, 1       ;blue
    shl al, 2  
    or al, 20       ;green
    shl al, 2    
    or al, 50       ;red

    mov es:[di], al         ;video

    

Draw2:
    pop dx
    xor ah, ah
    mov al, dh
    push dx
    mov bx, 320
    mul bx
    pop dx
    add al, dl
    jnc Pixel2
    inc ah

Pixel2:
    push dx
    mov di, ax
    mov bl, 128
    mov es:[di], bl

Var:
    xor ah, ah
    int 16h
    cmp al, 27
    jz Program_End_Helper2
    cmp ah, 75
    jz Left
    cmp ah, 77
    jz Right
    cmp ah, 72
    jz Up
    cmp ah, 80
    jz Down
    jmp Var

Program_End_Helper:
    jmp Program_End 

Var2:                   ;Second player control: w,a,s,d
    xor ah, ah
    int 16h
    cmp al, 27
    jz Program_End_Helper2
    cmp al, 'a'
    jz Left2
    cmp al, 'd'
    jz Right2
    cmp al, 'w'
    jz Up2
    cmp al, 's'
    jz Down2
    jmp Var2



Left:
    pop dx
    dec dl
    cmp dl, 1
    jnc Store
    inc dl
    jmp Store
    
Right:
    pop dx
    inc dl
    cmp dl, 250
    jc Store
    dec dl
    jmp Store

Up:
    pop dx
    dec dh
    cmp dh, 1
    jnc Store
    inc dh
    jmp Store

Down:
    pop dx
    inc dh
    cmp dh, 200
    jc Store
    dec dh
    jmp Store

Store:
    push dx
    jmp Draw

Program_End_Helper2:
    jmp Program_End 

Left2:
    pop dx
    dec dl
    cmp dl, 1
    jnc Store2
    inc dl
    jmp Store2
    
Right2:
    pop dx
    inc dl
    cmp dl, 250
    jc Store2
    dec dl
    jmp Store2

Up2:
    pop dx
    dec dh
    cmp dh, 1
    jnc Store2
    inc dh
    jmp Store2

Down2:
    pop dx
    inc dh
    cmp dh, 200
    jc Store2
    dec dh
    jmp Store2

Store2:
    push dx
    jmp Draw2

Program_End:
    mov ax, 03h
    int 10h
    pop dx
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h

gamestart: db '1. Start game$'
empty: db '                                                                   $'
exit: db '2. Exit$'


Code    Ends

Data    Segment

Data    Ends

Stack   Segment

Stack   Ends
    End Start
```

I tried bx instead of dx for the second one, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Less important:
You should handle them both in the same way. The right way to do this would be to redirect the keyboard interrupt to a special handler the gets the key-code and then calls a unified draw function that takes the 2 args.

What seems to be the real problem:
The Var2 function is never being called, also you should not preform your interrupt checks in two functions. There should be one function that waits for a keypress then another function that handles it depending on which key was pressed. I would merge Var and Var2.

I think something like this is what you need:

```
Var:
    ;get imput
    xor ah, ah
    int 16h

;check for quit
cmp al, 27
jz Program_End_Helper2

;player1
cmp ah, 75
jz Left
cmp ah, 77
jz Right
cmp ah, 72
jz Up
cmp ah, 80
jz Down

;Player 2
cmp al, 'a'
jz Left2
cmp al, 'd'
jz Right2
cmp al, 'w'
jz Up2
cmp al, 's'
jz Down2

;reloop
jmp Var
```

Comment: Yeah you are right. The reason why I don't do that because then Program_End_Helper does not work for some reason. It only work for some reason if it is between the two player controllers. I think it could be fix if i could jump longer somehow, However you can only do ljmp, but not ljz and I have to use ljz in the beginning of my program.

Comment: Use a short jump to a long jump:

Comment: jz extended_Program_End_Helper

Comment: and have extended_Program_End_Helper near that section
then in extended_Program_End_Helper use: ljmp Program_End_Helper

Comment: wait.. no the problem is you are using Program_End_Helper2

Comment: I'll try it thanks

Comment: I think using Program_End_Helper insted of Program_End_Helper2 would resolve that problem, I don't see why you have Program_End_Helper and Program_End_Helper2, I think it would be best to just use Program_End_Helper

Comment: I solved it in the end by basically just jumping above it. Here's the code if you want to know:
Var:
 xor ah, ah
 int 16h
 cmp al, 27
 jz Program_End_Helper2
 cmp ah, 75
 jz Left
 cmp ah, 77
 jz Rigth
 cmp ah, 72
 jz Up
 cmp ah, 80
 jz Down
 jmp Var2

Program_End_Helpet:
 jmp Program_End

Var2:
 cmp al, 'a'
 jz Left2
 cmp al, 'd'
 jz Rigth2
 cmp al, 'w'
 jz Up2
 cmp al, 's'
 jz Down2
 jmp Var

Comment: OK glad you resolved it.

Answer (score -1):

Found out how. Since dx is a stack you can you multiple data in it. If I have to use one I just have to take out the rigth one

Comment: DX is a 16-bit register composed of DH and DL 8-bit halves, but it's not a stack.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).